# defining operator + for double and string data types in cpp

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, explicit-conversion

I am trying to define operator + for string and double using the following function

```
string operator + (const double& b,const string a){
    return to_string(b)+a;
}
```

When I am doing the following operation, it works well

```
double c = 100.256;
string d = "if only";
cout<<c+d<<"\n";
```

but when i pass const char instead of string , it throws compilation error(invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘const char [4]’ to binary ‘operator+’)

```
double c = 100.256;
string test = c+"sff";
```

Why is implicit conversion of const char[] "sff" to string not happening?

Comment: Well because a char * is not a string

Comment: And you better accept your double by value, and string by a const reference

Comment: @pm100: there is an implicit convertion from `const char *` to `std::string`. The good answer would be why it cannot be used here.

Comment: Try `std::string operator+(const double b, std::string_view a)
{
  return std::to_string(b) + std::string(a);
} std::string test = c + "sff"s; 
`

Comment: @pm100 That wasn't a useful comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (16.3.1.2 Operators in expressions)

> 1 If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a
> class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in
> operator and interpreted according to Clause 8.

In this expression

```
c+"sff"
```

(where `c` is a scalar value of the type `double`) neither operand has a class or an enumeration type and a built-in operator + for types `double` and `const char *` is not defined. The pointer arithmetic is defined when a second operand has an integer type.

Comment: Can using a struct also (In addition to class, enum) allow an addition. IOW, is my  answer correct? Someone DVoted but didn't tell the reason.

Comment: @anki, a `class` in the C++ standard usually refers to both `struct` and `class`